# What are common services that are being misused in UDP amplification DDoS attacks?

Tags: ddos, udp

I have been learning about DDoS attacks and how to protect from it. I have a question regarding DDoS attacks. What are common services that are being misused in UDP amplification DDoS attacks?

Answer (score 1):

The US-CERT [lists a few](https://www.us-cert.gov/ncas/alerts/TA14-017A). That list can also be easily found using a web search engine and the keywords in your question:

> - DNS
> - NTP
> - SNMPv2
> - NetBIOS
> - SSDP
> - CharGEN
> - QOTD
> - BitTorrent
> - Kad
> - Quake Network Protocol
> - Steam Protocol
> - RIPv1
> - Multicast DNS (mDNS)
> - Portmap

Comment: Thanks, but can you answer a bit ditailed? I mean, why those services are misused?

Comment: Because they can. They do let you command other machines to send data to a determined destination.